Parametric circuits and QASM3 in Qiskit v1.1.0
I am currently exploring Qiskit v1.1.0 and its handling of QASM3. The following snippet demonstrates the creation of a parametric circuit and the generation of its corresponding QASM3 code. Subsequently, I reload the QASM3 code into another parametric circuit. However, I encounter an issue when attempting to instantiate the parameters in the final step (see the last commented line). Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
from qiskit.qasm3 import dumps
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit import transpile, assemble, qasm3
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

# Step 1: Define parameters
theta = Parameter('theta')
phi = Parameter('phi')

# Create a quantum circuit with 2 qubits
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# Add parameterized gates
qc.rx(theta, 0)
qc.ry(phi, 1)
qc.cx(0, 1)

# Draw the original circuit
qc.draw('mpl')

# Step 2: Generate QASM 3 code
qasm_str = dumps(qc)
print("Generated QASM 3 code:")
print(qasm_str)

dag = circuit_to_dag(qasm3.loads(qasm_str))
recreated_circuit = dag_to_circuit(dag)
recreated_circuit.draw()

parameter_values = {theta: 1.57, phi: 3.14}
#bound_circuit = recreated_circuit.assign_parameters(parameter_values, inplace=True)


When you load the circuit from QASM file, the circuit parameters have same names are before, but they are not the same Parameter instances.
You can avoid this issue by initializing the parameter dictionary as follows:
parameter_values = {'theta': 1.57, 'phi': 3.14}

Another method is to iterate over recreated_circuit parameters and set their values:
parameter_values = {}
for param in recreated_circuit.parameters:
    parameter_values[param] = 1.57 if param.name == 'theta' else 3.14

bound_circuit = recreated_circuit.assign_parameters(parameter_values, inplace=False)

Note also that, for bound_circuit to have a value, inplace should equal False.
